# Wake from suspend on power or external monitor plugged in

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

I have a HP Spectre x360 running Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3. Suspend works fine but I would like to have the computer to wake up from suspend either when the external power cable is connected or when an external monitor is connected. Is this possible? I can't find any of these setting in Gnome Tweaks or in Settings